# What trajectory minimizes the time traveling between two points under constant acceleration given initial and final position and velocity?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, optimal-control

I was wondering if there is an (analytical) solution to the problem where the position $\vec{r}_i = \vec{r}(t=t_i)$, $\vec{r}_f = \vec{r}(t=t_f)$ and the velocities $\vec{v}_i = \vec{v}(t=t_i)$, $\vec{v}_f = \vec{v}(t=t_f)$ as well as the magnitude of acceleration $|a|$ are given and the goal is to find the vector $\vec{a}(t)/|a| = \vec{e}_a(t)$ that minimizes the time need to transition from the initial state to the final state assuming there are no other forces present.

I tried to find an answer to this but all paper I could find on this topic dealt with spacecraft trajectory optimization and had the addition of a central force which made the problem much more complex.

I don't know much about optimal control and boundary value problems so and extended answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Can you post a link to the paper? Surely if that's the case, you can reduce their problem to yours by setting the central force to zero or something.

Comment: This one for example: http://vdol.mae.ufl.edu/JournalPublications/JSR-2014-10-A33187.pdf
As I said I don't know much about this topic and I don't see an obvious way to simplify the solution presented in this paper but if you can help that would be great!

Comment: The paper carefully sets up the problem and then exhibits numerical solution techniques and numerical solutions.  While that is useful and practical, I believe you are looking for a way to attack the simpler no-potential problem analytically.  Right?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for! But I couldn't find any papers that discussed simpler scenarios and the math surrounding the coordinates used in astronomy makes it even harder to understand.

Comment: The minimum time solution will consist of two phases of acceleration direction, changing abruptly at s specific time $t_c < t_f$.  The azimuth and elevation angles of the two phases' accelerations, along with the final and critical turning times (six variables) may be found by solving the velocity equations (three algebraic equations in time, and containing products of trig functions of the angles)  for final velocity components), and three equations quadratic in time for the three final position components. The equations are messy enough that they are not enlightening.

Comment: I tried your approach but I think that didn't get me any closer to a solution but I found a paper that discusses the problem I described (http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/pubs/PiZoWe2008/PiZoWe2008.pdf). On p.4 a solution is proposed and I think I do understand the basics: I know about Lagrangian multipliers and after reading the Wikipedia page I understand the shooting method but I am not able to put it all together especially how to solve the 2D ode's and if I should replace the control vector $\vec{u}$ in the hamiltonian with the proposed optimal vector $\vec{u}^*$. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Without any other constraints, the time optimal solution to the BVP $r(0) = r_0$, $r(1) = r_f$ on $[0,1]$ for the ode $\ddot{r} = a(t)$ is along a straight line connecting the boundary points, so

$$\frac{a(t)}{|a|} = \frac{r_f-r_0}{|r_f-r_0|}.$$

To meet the velocity requirement, you need only suitably throttle $|a|$.

You probably have only found literature for optimal trajectories in a potential field because that problem is (a) classic and used frequently in spacecraft guidance, and (b) nontrivial.

Comment: This solution does not work. It does not account for the arbitrary nature of v_i and v_f. For example, if v_i is perpendicular to the line from r_0 to r_f, then a straight-line trajectory is impossible.